# Can a function that maps one-one have more than one point that lies on the line of symmetry $y=x$?

Tags: functions

As far as I'm aware, a function $f$ which maps one-one must have an inverse function $f^{-1}$, and the graphs of these functions must intersect at some point (if their domains permit this) on the line of symmetry $y=x$.

Therefore, a function $f$ which maps one-one must have at least one point that lies on the line of symmetry $y=x$.

Can there be more than one such point?

Or is it the case that, if there is more than one point on a curve which lies on the diagonal $y=x$, that curve is either not the product of a function at all, or if it is the product of a function, the product of a function which maps many-one rather than one-one?

Comment: $y=x|x|$ is such a a function. I have no idea what you mean by product of a function

Comment: @geetha290krm I meant graph; my apologies.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the function $f(x) = x$. It has more than one point where it "intersects" the line $y=x$ (in fact, on every point).

If this example is unsatisfactory, consider $x+\sin x$. It is strictly increasing, therefore one-one, and at every $x=k\cdot\pi,k\in\mathbb{Z}$ its graph crosses the line $y=x$.

Answer (score 2):

> As far as I'm aware, a function $f$ which maps one-one must have an
> inverse function $f^{-1}$, and the graphs of these functions must
> intersect at some point (if their domains permit this) on the line of
> symmetry $y=x$.
>
> Therefore, a function $f$ which maps one-one must have at least one
> point that lies on the line of symmetry $y=x$.

No, there is no reason why the graphs of the function $f$ and $f^{-1}$ should intersect. You can take the function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ defined as $f(x)=x+1$. This function is clearly one to one, with the inverse being $f^{-1}(x)=x-1$.

However,

- The graphs of the two functions do not intersect.
- Neither of the functions intersects with the line $y=x$.

---

> Can there be more than one such point?

Yes, a graph of a one to one function **can** have more than one point on the line $y=x$. For example, the graph of the identity function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$, $f(x)=x$, has **all** of its points on that line.

---

In fact, is is actually possible to show that the graph of a one to one function can intersect in **almost any** possible subset of the line $y=x$.

**Statement**:

Let $A$ be a subset of the line $y=x$ (i.e., $A\subseteq\{(x,x)|x\in\mathbb R\}\subseteq \mathbb R^2$). Let $A$ be such that at least two points of the line $y=x$ are **not** on in $A$.

Then, there exists a one to one function $f:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ such that the graph of the function $f$ intersects the line $y=x$ at the set $A$, i.e. $$\{(x,f(x))|x\in\mathbb R\}\cap \{(x,x)|x\in\mathbb R\} = A$$

**Proof**:

Let $A'=\{x| (x,x)\in A\}$ be the projection of $A$ to $\mathbb R$. Then, by assumption, $B=\mathbb R\setminus A$ contains at least two points. Therefore, there exists some derangement of $B$, i.e. there exists some bijective function $g: B\to B$ such that for all $x\in B\colon g(x)\neq x$.

Define the function $f$ as follows:

$$f(x) = \begin{cases}
x& (x,x)\in A\\
g(x) & (x,x)\notin A
\end{cases}$$

The function $f$ then:

1. Is well defined, because if $(x,x)\notin A$, then $x\notin A'$ which means $x\in B$, and $g(x)$ is defined.
2. Is one to one, because its inverse is $$f^{-1}(x) = \begin{cases}
   x& (x,x)\in A\\
   g^{-1}(x) & (x,x)\notin A
   \end{cases}$$
3. Has a graph that intersects with the line $y=x$ at exactly $A$, because if the point $(x,f(x))$ is on the line $y=x$, then $x=f(x)$, and this is only possible if $x\in A'$ (because if $x\notin A$, then $x\in B$ which means $f(x)=g(x)\neq x$ by the property of $g$.